# IMU connection to Arduino

Tags: arduino, imu

I want to connect the [LSM6DS3TR-C](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lsm6ds3tr-c.pdf) IMU chip to an Arduino via I2C, but I don't know how exactly to do it properly. What can I do wrong in this wiring diagram?

[image: My scheme in Eagle]

[image: Wiring diagram from STM documentation]

Comment: Have you read the datasheet description how to use each pin?

Comment: Yes, I read how to use the pins, but since this is the first time I use a chip instead of a ready-made module, I would like to make sure that I did everything correctly before printing the board.

Comment: OK, then if you really want to use I2C, I suggest double checking how to use the CS and SA0 pins. And if you have no use for interrupt pins then that is your decision. And depending on what I2C speeds you want to use the pull-ups might be fine or not.

Comment: Now I see that in order to activate the I2C, the CS pin must be connected to 3.3V and the SA0 pin must be connected to ground or 3.3V. Thank you for your responses! I will continue to study the I2C hardware implementation to determine the speeds and resistors.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good! Make sure in routing you place the decoupling caps close to the VCC pins, and make sure to separate the SCL, SDA lines with some gap to avoid cross-talk. Finally you might want to add a connection to an interrupt pin. Even if you're not planning to use them, they can be useful.